# Display contents of a page as soon as it loads, as part of a dashboard style site with widgets

Tags: asp.net, ajax

So I'm working on a dashboard like app that has 8 different widgets that come up in the same page (index). All 8 pages talk to SQL server and might load slow at one point or another.

I'm looking for the best method to load the page first thing and display each widget as soon as the data is available, and not wait for all 8 widgets to be ready before i see  anything but a blank page.

The current method uses includes and ajax but is not ideal and causes other problems.

JDash looks good but is quite too complex for my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ajax to fetch dashboard item will be the best option.

You can try with calling the same function to the ajax success event with the next dashboard item.